# Replace FS5/FS2 starter with S10?

Tags: electrical

for a jukebox restoration project (changing T12 lamps to T8 by replacing lamp + ballast, the juke uses one ballast and starter per lamp), I am looking for the correct starter of the TL lamp.

The juke states that it uses FS5 and FS2 starters, the lamps are currently F20T12 and F4T5.

Would I be correct in assuming that these both can be replaced with the newer S10 starter by philips ?
https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00BFT1RC0/ref=zg_bs_10388864031_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=CZDKH5B6TX3JA17JQYEM

Comment: In the U.S. old mag ballasts were outlawed in 2002 or 2004 I don’t remember as it was delayed several times. Since then all ballasts are electronic and no longer need a starter. Since you are updating you might consider a frosted T8 led instead of the fluorescent. But it would be obvious a change as most led tubes  only have 120 deg beam angle.

Answer (score 2):

### The starter is *part of the ballast*

So it goes with the ballast.

Changing from T12 to T8 is a good thing to do.  You have to change the ballast.

T8 ballasts are almost universally electronic ballasts, *do not use starters*, and use one of two wiring schemes.

Old-style ballasts that use starters use quite a different wiring scheme.

Your new ballast includes a wiring diagram, either on the label or its instructions/data sheet.  **You will need to convert to this new wiring scheme.  It will not involve starters**.  So there is no reason to be shopping for starters, unless (amazingly) your T8 ballast requires one, in which case you'll need to use the starter it proscribes.

### Choices of ballast type

Since a starter based lamp does use preheats, that means your lampholders will be 2-wire (non-shorting).  That means you can use any modern T8 ballast (which matches your bulbs): **instant-start, rapid-start or programmed-start**.

- Instant-start ballasts don't use the preheaters, and strike the arc with sheer brute force: a big voltage spike. This is hard on the tube, and will necessitate more frequent tube changes. (that's relevant if the tube is difficult to change).
- Rapid-start ballasts do the same thing starters do; they use the pre-heater filaments before striking the arc, to ease wear and tear on the tubes.
- Programmed-start ballasts preheat intelligently, actively monitoring tube conditions until the ideal arc strike. These are far easiest on the tube; the tubes can even outlast LEDs! However, this patient preheating can annoy; for instance at -20C they can take 4-5 seconds to start.

Keep in mind T8 ballasts won't feel traditional; they won't flicker at 100Hz, won't flash on and off at times, and won't perform horribly in the cold.  Also, the T8 tubes will have good clean >80 CRI light.

Comment: I have installed these from robertson already, in combination with the current old starters and older tl bulbs. I've been trying to find a mini T5 bulb in led to go full led but they simply don't exist (yet). The diagram states they're electro magnetic starters. https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://s3.amazonaws.com/rww-w2m/CC1420.pdf

Comment: @user3263070 if you found this answer helpful, please click the check mark so others know that it's been resolved. That helps make the system work better for everyone.